# Como hago para intercambiar pixeles de una imagen?

Tags: c

Con el objetivo de hacer un efecto espejo, o reflejo. teniendo en cuenta que tengo la altura y el ancho en forma de array

Comment: Una imagen es una matrix de `NxM`, pero si la representación de la imagen esta en un array ("una única fila") el tamaño de este array es igual a la multiplicación de `N * M` (ej: si `N = 5` y `M = 8` el tamaño del array sería `5*8 = 40`), el tema es que los primeros 5 elementos del array corresponden a la primera fila, los siguientes 5 a la segunda fila y así sucesivamente, lo que se debe de hacer es primero es averiguar cuales de los pixeles de la matriz cuadrada (x,y) son los que se va  cambiar a su función espejo y luego transformarlos en una posición del array (`x*5 + y`)

Comment: tu problema parece simple, tal vez sea bueno que detalles exáctamente que quieres lograr, por ejemplo podrías poner un array inicial pequeño y una array final de como quieres que se vea luego de aplicar tu función.

Comment: otra cosa, no era necesario crear otro post, creo que puedes editar tu post inicial, dando más detalles, tal vez debas considerar leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).